# Core Data: save error after deleting objects with a non-optional relationship

Tags: macos, core-data, relationship

I have a simple data model: a parent entity in an optional one-to-many relationship with a child entity. The inverse relationship (child -> parent) is mandatory (non-optional).

After a child object is deleted, Core Data refuses to save, complaining about a missing required property in the child entity. The error goes away if the inverse relationship is made optional.

Why can I not have a mandatory inverse relationship where it is logical (*i.e.* a child *must* have a parent)? Why Core Data complains about a *deleted object's* inconsistency? Is this expected behaviour?

Thank you for any clarifications.

Edit: As requested, I am including a picture of my test data model:
[image: Test parent-child Core Data model]

As for the question about delete code, there is none. It's all done through `NSArrayController` bindings set up in the application window nib. You can load the test project here: [Parent-child test project](http://www.freefilehosting.net/testrelationship). It should probably be mentioned that this project is based on `NSPersistentDocument` architecture.

The behaviour I observe is as follows: if a parent is created without children, the document can be normally saved. If a child is created and then deleted, there is an error message on trying to save the document:
[image: Parent-child error message]

Comment: Please show us the model, the delete code and the error message.

Answer (score 3):

I've just discovered the answer to my own question.

The problem I was observing with objects lingering after deletion from the associated `NSArrayController` is related to the default operation of the controller's `-remove:` and `-removeObject:`methods. As per Apple docs ([NSArrayController -removeObject: method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSArrayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArrayController/removeObject%3a)):

> If, however, the receiver’s contentSet is bound to a relationship, removeObject: by default only removes the object from the relationship (not from the object graph). You can, though, set the “Deletes Object on Remove” option for the contentSet binding, in which case objects are marked for deletion as well as being removed from the relationship.

This applies equally to the `-remove:` method. Setting 'Deletes Object on Remove' in the child array controller contentSet binding solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  It had me puzzled for ages.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you got it the other way round?

> The **child**'s to-one relationship to the parent should **not** be optional.
>   The **parents**'s to-many relationship to the children **should** be optional.

I just tested this setup, and it works.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I have (see the added detail in the post). So far I did not do it in code, nor did I intend to before this problem. Maybe there is something strange going on in the persistent document stack, but I expected such simple things to work out of box.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your additional information, one thing pops out: the **delete rule**.

Let's think for a moment what might happen with the `Cascade` setting of your `children` relationship.

```
Child deleted --> cascade = parent deleted --> possible other orphaned children
```

Maybe that is what is happening? Try setting the delete rule to `Nullify`.

Comment: According to Apple, my model appears correct including the delete rules, supposing that a child must have one and one only parent (see [Relationship Definitions in the Model](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html)). But I found where I was wrong :-) (see my own answer).